# Cassandra Chunk Cache

Tags: caching, cassandra

I cannot find good documentation regarding 'Chunk Cache' in Cassandra.

I see some stats in 'nodetool info' but I cannot find reference online.

Could someone explain how this cache works and how (if possible) to configure it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a cache of chunks of SSTables for speeding up read operations. You configure this by changing `file_cache_size_in_mb` in `cassandra.yaml`. You can read more about the implementation in [CASSANDRA-5863](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-5863)